# Display image file name in AE viewport

Tags: after-effects

When there's a file missing in the imported image sequence, there is a filename displayed in the corner. Is there a way in After Effects to have the file name displayed all the time even on non-missing frames? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion might help you

```
https://video.stackexchange.com/a/26424/4426
```

It was relating to audio files, but the principle is the same.

You would make a text layer, then apply this expression to the Source Text field in the text layer:

```
thisComp.layer(2).name
```

Anything on layer 2 in the comp would then have its file name displayed in the text layer.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start, but the expression only displays the whole image sequence name C_[2500-6640 ], which is basically a layer name. It doesn't show the individual frame name (dynamically, like the missing frames layout does).